# List all apps installed on remote PC on a web page

Tags: windows, powershell, web, batch-file, vbscript

I want create a web page that can lists all apps installed on remote PC, and then I can chose which one to uninstall sliently. where should I start from? any suggestions? 
Now i m only using

---

psexec.exe -cd \computername "path\MsiZap.exe" TW {GUID for the Program to be removed}

---

to uninstall, but it can only remove the entry from [programs and features], the software is still on the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic /node:computername /user:adminuser /password:password /output:"path\to\index.html" product list /format:HTABLE
```

will generate a nice HTML page showing installed apps.

```
wmic /node:computername /user:adminuser /password:password product where name="name of program" call uninstall
```

will call the uninstaller for a program.

I leave it to you to get from point A to point B.  :)

For what it's worth, I sincerely doubt you'll be able to launch the uninstaller from a web page, as browser security generally frowns on a web page trying to run a command on the viewer's computer.