# OS Name Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, operating-system, windows-7-x64, placeholder

I would like to run a script where I can get the windows Name and version of the system of all computers running in the company, put it in a text fil. Then make a system variable out of my windows name . I know what to run but where I am running into an issue is a place holder. so here is my code:

```
    :OS_NAME
    Set OS_NAME= systeminfo | find "OS Name"

    :OS_Ver
    Set OS_Version= systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Version"

    systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /c:"BIOS Version" |  >> G:\Directory\%Computername%

    :OS_Arch
    IF exist "%programfiles(x86)% (SET OS_ARCH=X64)
    Else (SET OS_ARCH=X86)

    :Win_7
    systeminfo | find "Microsoft Windows 7" > nul
        if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
            goto ver_7)


    :Ver_7
    Set Win7= systeminfo | find "Microsoft Windows 7"
    Echo %computername% is running %WIN7% in %OS_ARCH% Environment >> G:\Directory\Win7Comps.txt
```

So basically I would like a place holder for the results of Systeminfo which i can refer to and parse it my SET command when I am making my system variables.

Thanks, any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but the biggest problem I see is that `systeminfo` takes forever to run and returns much more information than you're looking for.  You'd be better off capturing wmi queries using `wmic`.  This is basically a rewrite of your example script, just using `wmic` rather than `systeminfo`.  It should be much, much faster.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set prefix=G:\Directory

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==|" %%I in (`wmic os get name^,version /format:list`) do 2>NUL set "%%I=%%J"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic bios get version /format:list') do set "bios=%%I"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic computersystem get model /format:list') do set "model=%%I"

>>"%prefix%\%COMPUTERNAME%" echo OS Name: %name%
>>"%prefix%\%COMPUTERNAME%" echo OS Version: %version%
>>"%prefix%\%COMPUTERNAME%" echo PC Model: %model%
>>"%prefix%\%COMPUTERNAME%" echo BIOS Version: %bios%

if defined PROGRAMFILES(x86) (set arch=X64) else set arch=X86

if "%name%" neq "%name:Windows 8=%" (
    set out=%prefix%\Win8Comps.txt
) else if "%name%" neq "%name:Windows 7=%" (
    set out=%prefix%\Win7Comps.txt
) else if "%name%" neq "%name:Windows Vista=%" (
    set out=%prefix%\WinVistaComps.txt
) else if "%name%" neq "%name:Windows XP=%" (
    set out=%prefix%\WinXPComps.txt
)

>>"%out%" echo %COMPUTERNAME% is running %name% in %arch% environment
```

Type `wmic /?` for more info, and try `wmic computersystem get /?` or similar to see a list of items that can be queried under each class.

---

`wmic` is the Swiss Army knife of Windows.  Fun fact: you can even use `wmic` to [generate a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880444/1683264) table of installed software on a remote system.

Comment: Your Script is amazing! and works flawlessly!! Can you please break it down for me? or add comments in there?

Comment: @Sami_Sheikh - Sure, but probably not till Monday.  If I get a chance, I'll insert exhaustive comments and put it up on pastebin or similar for you.

Comment: @Sami_Sheikh - OK, I pastebinned a [heavily commented version](http://pastebin.com/U8g3S6gh) of this script for you.

Comment: Thank you sooo much Rojo! You're Awesome!! Can you please let me know if I also wanted the Physical ram added as a sys variable, and wanted to pull the information from systeminfo or wmic how would i do that? For instance I would like to do get just the total Ram using systeminfo |find "Total Physical Memory" or Wmic memorychip get capacity  and add it as a sys variable, then get detailed info using mic MEMORYCHIP get banklabel, capacity, caption, devicelocator, partnumber and put it in the textfile i generate for each comp. I can send you the script I have so far and perhaps you can look?

Comment: Thank You So Very Much rojo for the given solution!

Answer (score 1):

You are giving batch a little too much credit.  If you ran `echo %OS_NAME%` it would literally echo `systeminfo | find "OS Name"`.  Variables in batch will always just expand, it won't process any further.  This will also more than likely try to run `find "OS Name"` when you try to set the variable as the <kbd>|</kbd> is not escaped nor enclosed in double quotes.

If you want to set the output of a command to a value you have to capture it in a `for` statement like this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| find "OS Name"') do set OS_Name=%%a
```

Then remove the leading spaces like this: (there is probably a better way to do this)

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%OS_Name%") do set OS_Name=%%a
```

A few things to note here.  1.) `"tokens=2 delims=:"` is setting the delimiter to <kbd>:</kbd> and it is selecting the second section only, which will pull only the part you want. 2.) the <kbd>|</kbd> is escaped with a <kbd>^</kbd>, this needs to be done in `for` loops or anything after that will attempt to execute as seperate commands. 3.) `"tokens=* delims= "` The token here is * which is all tokens.

A few other problems I found.

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /c:"BIOS Version" |  >> G:\Directory\%Computername%
```

This has an extra <kbd>|</kbd> character at the end.

```
IF exist "%programfiles(x86)% (SET OS_ARCH=X64)
Else (SET OS_ARCH=X86)
```

Two problems here, you didn't finish the double quote around the path, and `else` has to be on the same line as the ending parentheses of the if statement, like this:

```
IF exist "%programfiles(x86)% (SET OS_ARCH=X64
) Else (SET OS_ARCH=X86)
```

Otherwise it tries to process `else` as it's own command

Comment: You have a typo here: `1.) "tokens=2 delims= " is setting the delimiter to :` :)